# how do i unban user with discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

hey i need my code which i wrote fixed because it wont work here it is the terminal shows the args arent defined if there is some how a different way to do this its accepted too thanks in advance. <3

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const { Client, MessageEmbed } = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Client();
const token = 'tokengoeshere';


bot.on('message', message => {
  if (!message.guild) return;
  const ubWords = ["!unban", "?unban", ".unban","-unban","!ub","?ub",".ub","-ub"];
  if (ubWords.some(word => message.content.toLowerCase().includes(word)) ) 
    if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
      return message.reply(`, You do not have perms to unban someone`)
    }
    
    if(!message.guild.me.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
      return message.reply(`, I do not have perms to unban someone`)
    }
    
    let userID = args[0]
      message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans=> {
      if(bans.size == 0) return 
      let bUser = bans.find(b => b.user.id == userID)
      if(!bUser) return
      message.guild.members.unban(bUser.user)
})
});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        let userID = args[0]

        if (!userID) return message.reply("Please specify the user ID you wish to unban!")
        try {
            message.guild.fetchBans().then(bans => {
                if(bans.size === 0) {
                    return message.reply("There is no users banned!")
                } else {
                message.guild.members.unban(userID)
                }
            })
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define args like this:

`const args = message.content.slice('?'.length).trim().split(/ +/g)`

*Put it after the message.guild check*